# How to inject jsx in a different html file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using create-react-app to build a pwa. I noticed that in index.html page there is no link to any js files whatsoever, so I just assumed there is some way for the CRA to inject jsx inside the 'root' div of index.html. Now I want to add an offline page as a fallback when the user'ss internet is off. Now how do I inject react elements into that second html page. I have no idea how, It'd be appreciated if someone would help.

Comment: I'm confused what you trying to do here. An offline page for user when internet is off? how  can user get this offline page if he has no internet?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use service worker for this scenario. Here is the link for your reference: https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/

Comment: I'm asking for how to inject jsx in react in a separate html file. :) cheers tho

Comment: React is a single-page application, every routing is to be done on the client-side. Thus, there's no need to "inject jsx in react in a separate html file" as React will only run on one index.html (that's why we called it SINGLE-PAGE application). You just need to create a react component and have ```BrowserRouter``` or ```HashRouter``` to point to that React component as your fallback page.

Comment: like how? So I have an offline page I want to display. That's is not possible with the default index.html file.

Comment: like how would you create an offline fallback page, with just a component.Post it as your answer please.